# Introductory ring theory: ring homomorphism (polynomials with coefficients in $\Bbb Q$)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Show that there is no ring homomorphism $h: \Bbb Q [x]/(x^2-2) \to \Bbb Q[x]/(x^2-3)$

I know that $h$ must satisfy:

(i) $h(1)=1$

(ii )$h(a+b)=h(a)+h(b)$

(iii) $h(ab)=h(a)h(b)$

But don't really know how to proceed...

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-d) \simeq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$(if d is square free), and generators must maps to generators(pardon my eng)

Comment: Is $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ meant to be the set $\{a+b\sqrt{2},a,b \in \Bbb Q\}$? and $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{3})=\{a+b\sqrt{3},a,b \in \Bbb Q\}$?

Comment: They are equal to those sets but those sets aren't truly the definitions. In other circumstances the set will look different - for instance, $\Bbb Q(e)$ does not equal $\{a+be:a,b\in\Bbb Q\}$ where $e$ is Euler's constant. The true definition of $K(x)$, where $K$ is a field and $x$ is an element of an extension field, is the *smallest field containing $x$ and $K$*. In practice this means $K(x)$ will be comprised of all rational expressions in $x$ with scalars from $K$. If $K=F(x)$ is of degree two over $F$, then $F(x)$ happens to be equal to $\{a+bx:a,b\in F\}$, which one can prove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there exists the ring homomorphism $h$, then by composing $h$ with the canonical map $\mathbb{Q}[x]\to\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-2)$, there is a ring homomorphism
$$
f\colon \mathbb{Q}[x]\to \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-3)
$$
such that $x^2-2\in \ker f$. The homomorphism $f$ is determined by $f(x)$, because $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-2)$ is a ring containing (a copy of) $\mathbb{Q}$, so $f(a)=a$, for all $a\in\mathbb{Q}$ (prove it).

Say $f(x)=p(x)+(x^2-3)$, with $p(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$; by using division with remainder, we can assume $p(x)=\alpha x+\beta$.

The fact that $x^2-2\in\ker f$ means then that
$$
(\alpha x+\beta)^2-2=\alpha^2x^2+2\alpha\beta x+\beta^2-2
$$
is divisible by $x^2-3$. Now
$$
\alpha^2x^2+2\alpha\beta x+\beta^2-2=
\alpha^2(x^2-3)+2\alpha\beta x+\beta^2-2+3\alpha^2
$$
so the condition is
$$
\begin{cases}
2\alpha\beta=0\\
3\alpha^2+\beta^2-2=0
\end{cases}
$$
However, $\alpha=0$ means $\beta^2=2$ and $\beta=0$ means $3\alpha^2=2$, but both equations have no solution in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: why is $x^2-2 \in ker(f)$?.. and why have you just substituted $p(x)$ for $x$ in $x^2-2$? (sorry I'm new to this whole ring business)

Comment: @Alex Because $x^2-2$ is in the kernel of the canonical map $\mathbb{Q}[x]\to\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-2)$. A ring homomorphism from a polynomial ring is determined by its action on the coefficients and the action on $x$; in this case the action on the coefficients is the identity; $p(x)$ is just the image of $x$ under $f$.

Comment: ok I see! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The key is to see that if a map preserves addition and multiplication then it preserves *relations* - that is, if an element satisfies a relation in the domain, then its image must satisfy a corresponding relation in the range. In particular, equations like $ x\cdot x=1+1$ are relations. What happens when you apply a ring homomorphism to both sides of that equation? It says the image of $x$ satisfies the *same* equation! But does any element of $\Bbb Q[y]/(y^2-3)$ satisfy that equation? (Prove your answer, of course.)

Comment: applying $h$ to equation $xx=1+1$: $h(xx)=h(1+1)=h(1)+h(1)=2=h(x)h(x)$. So $h(x)=\sqrt{2}$ which can't be an element of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{3})$. So is the point to find such an element $x \in \Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ so that $xx=2$?

Comment: which is basically $x=\sqrt{2} \in \Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})$....

Comment: @Alex We start out from the *outset* knowing $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ has a square root of two, so no that is *not* what we're trying to show. Remember, we're trying to show there is no isomorphism, which means we want to assume there is an isomorphism and show that leads to a contradiction. If we do assume there is an isomorphism, then according to what I've said here the square root of two in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ must be sent to a square root of two in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{3})$. But is that possible, or in other words, is there a square root of two in that field? (You have to actually *prove* there isn't.)

Comment: ok so I actually have to prove that $\sqrt{2} \notin \Bbb Q(\sqrt{3})$. (I just took that for granted)

Comment: @Alex Yes, you must prove these sorts of things because appearances can be deceiving. For instance, is $\sqrt{3}$ a member of $\Bbb Q(i,e^{2\pi i/3})$? In fact, yes it is.